# Create folder/file and set permissions

Tags: windows, command-line, command-prompt

How to in XP from command line create folder/file and after that allow everything to everyone permissions ? I tried from properties, I deselect readonly but when I open properties again for that folder/file it is always READONLY.

Comment: This belongs to http://superuser.com

Answer (score 2):

You have to use "CACLS".
Use CACLS /help to have the documentation.
Here 2 exemples:
To give the full right to the user "user1" to the directory

```
CACLS c:\directory /E /T /C /G "user1":F
```

To give the full right to the user "user1" to the content of the directory

```
CACLS c:\directory\*.* /E /T /C /G "user1":F
```

Answer (score 0):

CACLS /help:

```
NOTE: Cacls is now deprecated, please use Icacls.
```

To give the full right to the user "user1" to the directory (Nicolas' example converted):

```
Icacls c:\directory /T /C /grant "user1":F
```