# Programatically assign network service access rights to folder using Delphi 2010

Tags: delphi, networking, service

I need the following information

1. How to get "C:\Document and settings\Network service" folder of XP OS
   programmatically from Delphi2010?
2. What is the equivalent of above folder in Vista and Win7 OS ?
3. I need to set the Network Service"
   account full rights for the above folder thru Delphi 2010

Any help on the above is highly appreciated!!
Thanks in adv
Ven

Comment: BTW, such logon type **does not** load user profile.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

1) For WinXP: Use SHGetFolderPath API with CSIDL CSIDL_PROFILE to get the folder of your own profile (e.g. "C:\Documents and Settings\Steve"), remove your own name (the Steve part) and add NetworkService (giving you "C:\Documents and Settings\NetworkService"). There seems to be no direct way to get the Documents and Settings folder.
(Example for SHGetFolderPath usage: http://delphi.about.com/od/kbwinshell/a/SHGetFolderPath.htm)

2) For Win7 the location changed to "%windir%\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService", this is commonly "C:\Windows\ServiceProfiles\NetworkService". Don't know for Vista, might be the same.

3) The easiest way seems to be the approach described here: [Create folder/file and set permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680019/create-folder-file-and-set-permissions)

You can start the CACLS programm via ShellExecute API. See example of usage here: http://delphi.about.com/od/windowsshellapi/a/executeprogram.htm

Comment: Hi Heinrich Ulbricht, Thank u very much for your suggestions and the tips.

Comment: Hi Heinrich Ulbricht, add the "network service" path to the "document and settings" is what i thought earlier. but i had a bit doubt on the localized name of this folder in other lang OS. i require a solution to get it running on XP and higher OS in all the language. Actually, i need the microsoft folder inside the network service folder.. sorry i forgot to mention this in my initial requirement. Actual folder name in XP is "C:\Document and settings\network service\Application data\microsoft". this i hv to get it manually like u suggested.

Comment: The "NetworkService" account is documented as that, so I would assume the name as quite fixed. Have a look here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684272%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: But only thing is the localized verison of this folder in different languages

Comment: i found the folder in Vista under %windir%, but i could not locate the applicationdata\microsoft folder. may be they are moved under "Roaming" folder

Comment: Well, maybe it was never intended to work with it like you try to ;)